# How can i Send a word or a pdf document directly to print dialogue without preview or download using php or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing

can anyone tell me how  i can print a word or a pdf document directly without preview or download using php or jquery ,  means directly open print dialogue and not allowing users to download that file  or preview that file

Comment: I'm wondering: Even if you find a solution somebody could always use "Save as PDF" in the print dialogue and save it anyway. Do you want this to secure your documents or as a way to enhance the UX in some way?

Comment: i want them to be able to print that document  on a click of a button

Comment: The only way would be to send the pdf directly from the server to the printer. But this then means, that your (php) server needs to have some sort of LAN connection to the printer and the user has to select that printer in your UI. On the server side usually it's CUPS or similar...

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [How can I print a PDF fetched via an ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397137/how-can-i-print-a-pdf-fetched-via-an-ajax-request)